# preg replace number and dots

Tags: php, preg-replace

I need to manipulate this number, for example:

1232345678

It has always 10 number

I need to convert it to:

123.23.45.678

I was able to obtain only this output:

123.2345678

with this code

```
$number2 = preg_replace('/^[0-9]{3}/', "$0.", $number);
```

but I don't know how to put the other dots.

Thanks

*Edit:*
The sequence for the number is: 3-2-2-3

Answer (score 0):

```
$number2 = preg_replace('/[0-9]{3}/', "$0.", $number);
```

Are you sure you gave the correct example in your question? I mean literally `123.23.45.678` and  not `123.234.567.8` ? The problem was in your ^ "start" character, it only matched the **first** three digits because of it

Comment: u copied the exact!! what's solution in this?

Comment: are you sure I copied the same? Did you make an effort to test it?

Comment: It's not working because it results as: 123.234.567.8, grouped by 3 numbers. Check better my answer

Comment: then if you really need to get 123.23.45.678 , what's the rule there? 3-2-2-3? or 3-2-2-everything else? Should you edit your question?

Comment: Try `echo preg_replace('/^(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{3})$/', "$1.$2.$3.$4", $number);` -- or have a look at [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)